# Firefox manipulation of saved form data

Tags: forms, firefox

Is there a Firefox plugin for manipulating and deleting saved form data?
In the browser there is only the option to delete all data.

Comment: I believe, you mean 'delete saved form' but not all. I too require this often. Like for cookies, there is an option to select site and delete the cookies set by that particular site.  Unfortunately this feature is not present in case of form data.

Answer (score 4):

[Form History Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12021) does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [SQLite Manager](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/) to access the form history database directly. Just select the profile `formhistory.sqlite`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using FFv 3.0.4.

Using Tools -> Clear Private Data,
invoke a pop-up.

From the pop-up dialog, you can decide what to clear

[] Browsing History [] Download History [] Saved Form and Search History <------ you are interested in this [] Cache [] Cookies [] Offline Saved data [] saved password [] authenticated session

hope this ans your question

Comment: I believe, he means 'delete saved form' but not all. Is there any plug-in? I too require this often. Like for cookies, there is an option to select site and delete the cookies set by that site.  Unfortunately this feature is not present for form data.